# ImportError: cannot import name 'trainer' from 'lib'

Tags: python, neural-network

I have downloaded perceptron package with `pip install perceptron`. However, it says that there is no module from lib and decided to download `pip install lib`. After that, I got error with this

[image: error]

> `ImportError: cannot import name 'trainer' from 'lib' (/home/deeplab307/anaconda3/envs/ochi/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lib/__init__.py)`

Comment: This is still an open issue in Perceptron git repo: https://github.com/rfguri/perceptron/issues/1 However, `import perceptron as pc` works fine though `from lib import trainer` still throws an ImportError.

Comment: The library has not been updated since 4 years, simply not use it and find another with the same functionality